# indexing in numpy (related to max/argmax)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an N-dimensional numpy array `x` and an (N-1)-dimensional index array `m` (for example, `m = x.argmax(axis=-1)`). I'd like to construct (N-1) dimensional array `y` such that `y[i_1, ..., i_N-1] = x[i_1, ..., i_N-1, m[i_1, ..., i_N-1]]` (for the `argmax` example above it would be equivalent to `y = x.max(axis=-1)`). 
For N=3 I could achieve what I want by

```
y = x[np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis], np.arange(x.shape[1]), m]
```

The question is, how do I do this for an arbitrary N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`reshaping`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and [`linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to handle multi-dimensional arrays of arbitrary dimensions -

```
shp = x.shape[:-1]
n_ele = np.prod(shp)
y_out = x.reshape(n_ele,-1)[np.arange(n_ele),m.ravel()].reshape(shp)
```

Let's take a sample case with a `ndarray` of `6 dimensions` and let's say we are using `m = x.argmax(axis=-1)` to index into the last dimension. So, the output would be `x.max(-1)`. Let's verify this for the proposed solution -

```
In [121]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,5,3,3,2,4))

In [122]: m = x.argmax(axis=-1)

In [123]: shp = x.shape[:-1]
     ...: n_ele = np.prod(shp)
     ...: y_out = x.reshape(n_ele,-1)[np.arange(n_ele),m.ravel()].reshape(shp)
     ...: 

In [124]: np.allclose(x.max(-1),y_out)
Out[124]: True
```

---

I liked [`@B. M.'s` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36317745/3293881) for its elegance. So, here's a runtime test to benchmark these two -

```
def reshape_based(x,m):
    shp = x.shape[:-1]
    n_ele = np.prod(shp)
    return x.reshape(n_ele,-1)[np.arange(n_ele),m.ravel()].reshape(shp)

def indices_based(x,m):  ## @B. M.'s solution
    firstdims=np.indices(x.shape[:-1])
    ind=tuple(firstdims)+(m,) 
    return x[ind]
```

Timings -

```
In [152]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,5,3,3,4,3,6,2,4,2,5))
     ...: m = x.argmax(axis=-1)
     ...: 

In [153]: %timeit indices_based(x,m)
10 loops, best of 3: 30.2 ms per loop

In [154]: %timeit reshape_based(x,m)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.14 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I would only add `.reshape(shp)` to the last line

Answer (score 2):

you can use [indices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) :

```
firstdims=np.indices(x.shape[:-1])
```

And add yours :

```
ind=tuple(firstdims)+(m,)
```

Then `x[ind]` is what you want.

```
In [228]: allclose(x.max(-1),x[ind]) 
Out[228]: True
```

Comment: Much more elegant! Make that `np.indices`?

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about that indices function.